Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware while deploying using docker file
We are using Easy OCR ultra analytics modal for one of the applications. We are taking video input and processing it using the modal to identify the text.
The code works fine on GPU & CPU. I deployed this on one of the client server using docker & jenkins. The code does get deployed.
But while processing the video it fails with error [W1102 18:08:49.641464899 NNPACK.cpp:61] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware & crashes the container
From these line we can say the video was getting processed before crashing with error.

Speed: 4.9ms preprocess, 434.4ms inference, 3.2ms postprocess per
image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)


Speed: 3.2ms preprocess, 401.5ms inference, 1.9ms postprocess per
image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)

Below is the requirement.txt used in docker file.
Flask==2.1.2
flask_cors==3.0.10
requests==2.27.1
ultralytics==8.0.134
Werkzeug==2.0.3
matplotlib>=3.2.2
numpy>=1.18.5
opencv-python-headless>=4.1.1  # Changed to headless version for server
Pillow<10.0.0  # Ensures no 'ANTIALIAS' issue
PyYAML>=5.3.1
requests>=2.23.0
scipy>=1.4.1
tqdm>=4.64.0
tensorboard>=2.4.1
pandas>=1.1.4
seaborn>=0.11.0
ipython
psutil
thop>=0.1.1

Dockerfile
# Use an official lightweight Python image
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Set environment variable
ENV USE_NNPACK=0

# Set up the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libgl1-mesa-glx \
    libglib2.0-0 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
    pip install easyocr==1.6.2 && \
    pip uninstall -y opencv-python-headless opencv-python && \
    pip install opencv-python

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 5001

# Run the application
CMD ["python", "ANPR_Test.py"]

How to fix this issue? I did try disabling USE_NNPACK in docker file.

Formally, you're not even asking a question. Is it why that happens or how to fix it? Have you tried running it with strace for example to find out what leads to the error? What exactly do you mean with "crashing"?

@UlrichEckhardt thank you for responding, I have edited and updated my question. By container crashing I mean that it stops with error exited - code 252. I tried to run strace but as container is crashing so we are not able to fetch real time logs.

CMD ["strace", "python", "ANPR_Test.py"] should get you started.

@UlrichEckhardt we tried running with the command CMD ["strace", "-o", "trace_output.txt", "python", "ANPR_Test.py"]. However, the container crashes as it begins processing video frames. This prevents us from monitoring real-time logs using tail -f trace_output.txt. Unfortunately, we are unable to gather any useful information from the logs because they reset each time the container gets crashed.
